# Smart cast to ‘CLASS!’ is impossible, because ‘VARIABLE’ is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

So I recently started learning Kotlin and I was following a tutorial for Android Studio in Java language. I eventually converted the Java file to Kotlin using Android Studio.

*Kotlin Code Snippet:*
[image: Kotlin Code Snippet]

*Compilation Error:*
[image: Compilation Error]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: please post all relevant information in the question itself

Comment: Sorry! this is my first post and I didn't know images would appear like this. I will remember it the next time I post a question.

Comment: when posting code or error messages, don't post images. post the actual code and text of the error as formatted text

Comment: Note you can edit the post and replace the images with code.

Comment: I also advise using a Kotlin-based tutorial instead of a Java-based one, because this isn't how such code is normally written in Kotlin (even though it can be made to work).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you post the code in your post itself. Coming to the error. Let's see your code. You have various properties assigned to null like this. Let us consider one of them.

```kotlin
var splashImg: ImageView? = null
```

The error you are getting implies since this a nullable property, there is no guarantee that when you are trying to access it is still an `ImageView` and not simply `null.`

The answer is simple, that is to add null check for them. For that kotlin has a safe call operator called `?.`

So when you are trying to access the property, access it as follows. This ensure it will only access it if it is not null. You can also put a normal `if-else`

```kotlin
splashImg?.animate()...
```